# How to use the API defined in 3rd party library in webpack+reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack + react as my application. Below is my index.jsx file.

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import load from 'little-loader';

import './main.css';
import './component';
import Search from './search/search'

load('http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=gNO2wKVBNupZfafi0bl0sW3dIKqAHn4l', function(err){
    console.log('err:', err);
});

// load('baidu.js');

// document.body.appendChild(component());


ReactDOM.render(<Search />, document.getElementById('search'));

var map = new BMap.Map("container");
```

It imports a third party javascript from this link: http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=gNO2wKVBNupZfafi0bl0sW3dIKqAHn4l.

If you open this link, the content is defined as follows:

```
(function(){ 
window.BMap_loadScriptTime = 
(new Date).getTime(); 
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=2.0&ak=gNO2wKVBNupZfafi0bl0sW3dIKqAHn4l&services=&t=20160401164342"></script>');
```

})();

Now I want to use the api from this library by

```
var map = new BMap.Map("container");
```

But I got an error complaining BMap is not defined. I guess I didn't import this library correctly, how should I import it?

My index.html looks like below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='search'>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's an async function. Move your code within the callback.

Comment: where should I add the callback? I tried to move it on the load callback function, it still has this issue.

Comment: Callback will not help since loaded js using `document.write`. You can simply move js from `load()` to `<head>` tag.

Comment: I have put my index.html on the post. I just tried to put it in the head tag but my application doesn't seem to be working. It shows a blank page without any error. Is there a way for me to package it on the bundle.js file like others?.

Comment: Cant open `baidu.com` from Russia and check docs lol. Do you have element with id `container` in your DOM? You can try to pass in `load` `http://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=2.0` and move `var map = new BMap.Map("container");` in `function(err){  .. }`

Comment: I do have the container dom. And the error is about not found BMap class. I moved it to the callback function(err){...} but still got the same error.